# Is it possible to make nesting schemes in each other? Json schema python

Tags: python, json, schema, jsonschema

I started to redo the tests for the validation of schemes. And the question arose: is it possible to put one scheme into another? For example(This is a rough example, but I think the essence is clear, what I would like):

```
class Schemas:

    schema_first = {
        '$schema': 'https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema',
        'title': 'schema_one',
        'type': 'object',
        'properties': {
            'Params': {
                'type': 'object',
                'properties': {
                    'Text': 'string',
                    'Count': 'integer'
                 },
                 "additionalProperties": False,
                 "minProperties": 2
            },
            'User': {
                'Name': 'string',
                'Id': 'integer'
            }
        },
        "additionalProperties": False,
        "minProperties": 1
    }

    schema_two = {
        '$schema': 'https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema',
        'title': 'schema_two',
        'Params': {
            'type': 'object',
            'properties': {
               'Text': 'string',
               'Count': 'integer'
            },
            "additionalProperties": False,
            "minProperties": 2
        }
    }
```

(That is, simply put, instead of the Params key in the scheme_first, make a reference to scheme_two. And so that it works correctly)

Comment: Could you clarify on which level you want to reference, how you plan to use the schema class and what validator you want to use? Right now, I'd say just string-concatenate `schema_two` (removing `$schema` & `title` attributes) into `schema_one` at the `Params` definition. Alternatively, there's the [`$ref` keyword](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#ref) that let's you reference local sub-schemas (`$defs`) or external schemas. How external schemas are retrieved is up to the validator's implementation.

Comment: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#bundling